# How do I turn this into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How do I turn this into an array if I want to include steve, john, bobby, and peter?

```
getBlogs('#all-blogs', blogUrl+ '?user=steve', 5, feedUrl);
```

-edit- More info

This is how it's set up right now with javascript.

```
function getBlogs(element, url, limit, feed){
        jQuery(element).load(url+ ' .blog_list:lt('+ limit+ ')', function(){

            jQuery(".postbody p:first").replaceWith(function() {
                return jQuery(this).contents();
            });
        });
    }

    var blogUrl = 'http://mysite.com/profiles/blog/list';
    var feedUrl = '/profiles/blog/feed';
    getBlogs('#all-blogs', blogUrl+ '?user=steve', 5, feedUrl);
```

Basically, I want to include john, bobby, and peter's blog posts in there.

Comment: Depends on the server side language you are using. Either by appending `&user=...` or adding `[]` to the parameters: `?user[]=steve&user[]=...`. I suggest you give some more information, e.g. where the names come from. Or serialize the array of names... e.g. to JSON.

Answer (score 3):

```
getBlogs('#all-blogs', blogUrl+ '?user=steve,john,bobby,peter', 5, feedUrl);
```

Then just split on commas on the server

Comment: `?user=` is part of the url. Sorry I didn't mention that. I added more info to the post on top. Each user has a url for their blog posts like this: `http://mysite.com/profiles/blog/list?user=steve`